# Data from scope getting loaded on clicking the button twice in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have button and on its click I call a function which sets some value in $scope.content and the that value is being displayed in a div.
Now the problem I am facing is that when I click the button the function is correctly called but the value in $scope.content is not getting reflected in the div. But when I click the button again the value is showing.

here is my view file

```
<body ng-app="starter">


    <ion-pane>

      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="SmsCtrl">
      <ion-item>

      <input id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter mobile number" value="" ng-model="form.number"type="tel" />
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
      <textarea id="messageTxt" placeholder="Enter message" ng-model="form.message"></textarea>
      </ion-item>
      <button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="sendSms()">Send SMS</button>
<input
           <button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="doContactPicker();">Pick Contact</button>

      <h1>data here</h1>
      <h2>{{ content }}</h2>
      <h2>{{ counter }}</h2>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

  </body>
```

and this my angular js file

```
var finalContacts="";
var contactCount=0;
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller('SmsCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaSms', function ($scope,$ionicPlatform,$cordovaSms) {
  console.log('enetered in ctrl');
  $scope.form={}
$scope.counter=contactCount

$scope.doContactPicker=function() {
    contactCount++;
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
        console.log('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
        //Build a simple string to display the Contact - would be better in Handlebars
        var s = "";
        /*s += "<h2>"+getName(contact)+"</h2>";*/

        if(contact.emails && contact.emails.length) {
            s+= "Email: "+contact.emails[0].value+"<br/>";
        }

        if(contact.phoneNumbers && contact.phoneNumbers.length) {
            s+= "Phone: "+contact.phoneNumbers[0].value+"<br/>";
        }

        if(contact.photos && contact.photos.length) {
            s+= "<p><img src='"+contact.photos[0].value+"'></p>";
        }

        finalContacts+=s;


        //$("#selectedContact").html("hello world");
        //document.querySelector("#selectedContact").innerHTML=finalContacts;
        //var markedStr =finalContacts;
        //$scope.content = markedStr;

    },function(err){
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    $scope.content="ERROR OCCURED";
    });
   /* $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { $scope.doContactPicker(); }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })*/

    $scope.content=finalContacts;

}
```

The problem I mentioned is with the line(in view file)

```
<button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="doContactPicker();">Pick Contact</button>
```

So the above button has to be pressed twice to get the data from scope.content loaded in the view.(the associated function is doContactPicker in js code above)

Answer (score 0):

Try using $timeout may help

```
     $timeout(function() {

      .......

      variables which are not loading

      ........
              }, 200)
```

Comment: thanks Jinna but This would be workaround and would delay the loading of data before the function executes. But This is not what I want to achieve. My function gets called and the does the intended task. Its just that the data written in the scope gets reflected on the second click which I am not able to figure out.